# Insert partial HTML file from Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a HTML page with `<select>` element with a few options.

```
<div id="par_id">
<select id="sel_id" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) insertFragmentPage()">
      <option value="1">case 1</option>
      <option value="2">case 2</option>
      <option value="3">case 3</option>
      <option value="4">case 4</option>
</select>
</div>

function insertFragmentPage() {
    var selectElement = document.getElementById("sel_id");
    var div = document.getElementById("par_id");
    var fragment1 = document.createElement("div");
    var fragment2 = document.createElement("div");
    if (selectElement.selectedIndex > 2) {
      if (selectElement.nextSibling != null) {
        div.removeChild(selectElement.nextSibling);
      }
      div.appendChild(CONTENT_OF_FRAGMENT1);
    } else {
      if (selectElement.nextSibling != null) {
        div.removeChild(selectElement.nextSibling);
      }
      div.appendChild(CONTENT_OF_FRAGMENT2);
    }
  }
```

CONTENT_OF_FRAGMENT1 and CONTENT_OF_FRAGMENT2 are files in the same directory named
frag1.html and frag2.html containg HTML code with root element `<form>`.

I know I could build this `<form>` element directly inside the function `insertFragmentPage()` but this wouldbe very painful job.

How would you append the content of those files from `Javascript`?

Comment: Try doing an ajax request to read the HTML page and store it into a temp variable, than load into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Well first we gonna make it using jquery,

```
var div = $('#par_id');
var fragment1 = "path to your file";
var fragment2 = "path to yoir file";
```

Then replace `div.appendChild(.....)` with

```
div.load(fragment1);
```

Or

```
div.load(fragment2);
```

If you wanna clear your div just use

```
div.html("");
```

Comment: And is it possible only with `Javascript`?

Comment: this won't work as shown, `load()` replaces container html, first load will wipe out what already exists, second load will wipe out the first

Comment: Hell, framents won't be loaded at same time, only one once time